# Make Qt menu appear programmatically

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

I have a `QMenu` in a `QMenuBar`.

I can make the `QMenu` appear via `QMenu.show()` `QMenu.exec()` and `QMenu.showTearOffMenu()`, but these show the menu at the top-left of the screen, at a prespecified position, or under the mouse. I want the menu to appear in its usual position (under the `QMenuBar`). Is this possible (in any Qt language)?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use

```
your_menuBar.addMenu(your_menu
self.setMenuBar(your_menuBar)
```

where self will correspond to QMainWindow

Refer
setMenuBar

> Sets the menu bar for the main window to menuBar.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setMenuBar

Answer (score 0):

In Qt, you can use the position of your menu bar and then to open the menu on that position:

```
poMenu->exec(mapToGlobal(m_poMenuBar->rect().bottomLeft()));
```